# Cloud Storage for Firebase SDK 6.1.0 : can't list files in a bucket using listAll()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to get a list of all files from folder using listAll() method but can't do it.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(userid + "/");

    console.log(storageRef.listAll());

    storageRef.listAll().then(function (result) {

        result.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
            imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                $("#album").append("<div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'><div class='card'><div class='card-img-top'><img src='" + url + "'></div></div></div>")
            }).catch(function (error) {

            });
        });
    }).
    catch(function (error) {

    });
});
```

Current Firebase Rule :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

I got this error `Listing objects in a bucket is disallowed for rules_version = "1". Please update storage security rules to rules_verison = "2" to use list.` inside console.

So what is this error tells? Am i need to change rule version inside firebase console? or should i make read and write rule to allow only authenticated user?

Answer (score 1):

In your security rules, you need to declare that you want to use security rules version 2.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior#security_rules_version_2):

> As of May 2019, version 2 of the Firebase security rules is now
>   available. Version 2 of the rules changes the behavior of recursive
>   wildcards {name=**}. You must use version 2 if you plan to use
>   collection group queries. You must opt-in to version 2 by making
>   rules_version = '2'; the first line in your security rules:
>
> ```
> rules_version = '2';
> ```

So, your minimal rules will have to look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that listing files was very recently released in the JavaScript SDK, but it has not been announced or fully documented.